# No carga los archivos con require_once en el servidor remoto, pero en local si, no veo por que razón

Tags: php, web, hosting, godaddy

Alguien que me oriente, por favor.
He construido mi página web  ya que en modo local si funciona, pero tengo problemas con mi web en mi servidor en GoDaddy cuando la subo no evalúa las condicionales if para requerir el archivo de la vista.

Este es mi código que uso cuando estoy en el servidor local:

```
define("base_url", "http://localhost/miProyecto/");
```

Y este es mi código que uso cuando subo mi pagina a el servidor de GodaDadd, este código se encuentra en mi carpeta config/parameters.php:

```
<?php

define('BASE_URL','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/');
define("controller_default","homeController");
define("action_default","index");
```

En el cual intento obtener mi directorio raíz de mi servidor, pero no funciona. Todo anda bien en local, pero en el servidor no.

Mi index.php tiene la siguiente estructura uso MVC:

```
<?php
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';
require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';


function show_error(){
  $error = new errorController();
  $error->index();
}

if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
  // code...
  $nombre_controlador=$_GET['controller'].'Controller';

}elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
  // code...
  $nombre_controlador=controller_default;
}else {
  require_once 'views/layout/header.php';
  show_error();
    exit;
}



if (class_exists($nombre_controlador)) {
  // a este codigo sele conoce como controlladpor frontal

  $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();



        if (isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador,$_GET['action'])) {
          // code...
          $action=$_GET['action'];
          $controlador->$action();

          }elseif(!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])){
              $action_default=action_default;
              $controlador->$action_default();
        }else {
          show_error();
        }




}else {

  show_error();
}
```

La estructura de mi .htaccess es:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#activar el rewrite

RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mg-solutions.com.mx/error/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

La estructura del autoload.php es:

```
<?php

  function controllers_autoload($className){// cargando la sclasees
    include 'controllers/'.$className.'.php';
  }


  spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');// se pasa como parametro la clase que va cargar, se aplica aun directorios
```

esta es la estructura de mis carpeta que manejo de forma local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando las subo a el servidor me las coloco dentro de la carpeta public_html y quedan de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que obtengo en mi web es este se muestra en blanco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero cuando examino el codigo veo que si carga el head, pero el el archivo del body no, y al ver el código veo que accede a mi dominio y seve  asi la parte de el head:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando mando a llamar los archivos del body sin usar la estructura MVC SI FUNCIONAN , PERO CUANDO PONGO LA ESTRUCTURA MVC NO JALAN A QUE SE DEBERA.
Por el momento no estoy trabajando con los modelos por que solo estoy mostrando las vistas con los controladores por ahora no uso BD.¿Cómo seria la forma de obtener LA BASE_URL?
Espero me orienten, gracias de antemano, soy nuevo en esto gracias.

Comment: Si imprimes el valor de `base_url`, ¿que resultado obtienes? Intenta usar `var_dump(base_url);` para ver dato y tipo de dato almacena esa constante.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿dentro de qué directorio se encuentra tu proyecto? ¿Puede ser que sea algo cómo `/public_html/mi_proyecto/`?

Comment: Cuando imprimo la variable con var_dump obtengo esto: string(40) "http://www.solutions.com.mx/index.php". Y mis archivos se encuentran dentro de la carpeta public_html

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta con 2 alternativas que pueden ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas definir la URL base de tu sitio o app web, esta es la mejor solución

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
```

`public_html` hace referencia a un directorio interno del servidor y normalmente éste se corresponde con `/`.

Por ejemplo, el directorio `/public_html/css/` se corresponde con `http://www.example.com/css/`.

Por otra parte, dependiendo de la configuración del servidor web, a veces no funciona correctamente. Para ese caso te sugiero dos alternativas

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Y

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', explode('/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])[0]);
```

Puedes conocer más sobre la variable `$_SERVER` en la [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: El proyecto está instalado en la carpeta public_html , No se encuentra contenido en ninguna sub carpeta.

Comment: Implemente el código pero no me funciono, he actualizado toda la pregunta para que se entienda mejor  saludos gracias por tu paciencia, ya que soy nuevo en esto.